# Nginx client_max_body_size for sub location

Tags: nginx

Say i have this (psuedo)

```
    server {
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://backend
        }
    }
```

and i want to add a sub location `/api/upload` where i set the 
`client_max_body_size`
and 
`client_body_buffer_size` 
that proxies to the same `http://backend`

How would i do this, do need to make a sub location under `/api` duplicate the proxy to backend config lines?

this did not work:

```
    server {
        location /api {
            location /api/upload {
               client_max_body_size 1M;
               client_body_buffer_size 1M;
            }
            proxy_pass http://backend
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: the client_max_body_size and client_body_buffer_size  are not set to 1M for request to /api/upload, even though the /api/upload location seems to be in effect 
if i define the client_max_body_size  and client_body_buffer_size  on the higher /api level, then they are correctly set to 1M

Answer (score 0):

server {
        location /api {
 proxy_pass http://backend
}
            location /api/upload {
               client_max_body_size 1M;
               client_body_buffer_size 1M;
            }
    }

Comment: from your answer i understand the proxypass should come first. I tried this, and it did not resolve the problem

Comment: @Alex have you been able to solve it?